# Is this EBNF method correct?

Tags: java, parsing, ebnf

I'm not sure if I'm translating the EBNF to code correctly so if someone can take a look at one of the methods I'm having a hard time doing that'll be great.

Here's the EBNF Grammar:

```
   program ::= P {declare} B {statemt} ;
   declare ::= ident {, ident} : V ;
   statemt ::= assnmt | ifstmt | doloop | read | output
   assnmt  ::= ident ~ exprsn ;
   ifstmt  ::= I comprsn @ {statemt} [% {statemt}] &
   doloop  ::= D {statemt} U comprsn T
   read    ::= R ident {, ident } ;
   output  ::= O ident {, ident } ;
   comprsn ::= ( oprnd opratr oprnd )
   exprsn  ::= factor {+ factor}
   factor  ::= oprnd {* oprnd}
   oprnd   ::= integer | ident | ( exprsn )
   opratr  ::= < | = | > | !
   ident   ::= letter {char}
   char    ::= letter | digit
   integer ::= digit {digit}
   letter  ::= X | Y | Z
   digit   ::= 0 | 1
```

The tokens are: P B ; , : V ~ I @ % & D U T R O ( ) + * < = > ! X Y Z 0 1

```
private void statemt(){
    if((token() == 'X') || (token() == 'Y') || (token() == 'Z')){
      assnmt();
    }else if(token() == 'I'){
      ifstmt();
    }else if(token() == 'D'){
      doloop();
    }else if(token() == 'R'){
      read();
    }else if(token() == 'O'){
      output();
    }
}
```

Is this if stmt method correct?

```
   private void ifstmt(){
     match('I');
     comprsn();
     match('@');
     while((token() == 'X') || (token() == 'Y') || (token() == 'Z')){
       statemt();
     }
     if(token() == '%'){
         match('%');
         statemt();
     }
     match('&');
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be far better to test for the statements that start with keywords first, and then fall into the assignment case if no keywords match. That way you don't need X,Y,Z as keywords:

```
private void statemt(){
    if(token() == 'I'){
      ifstmt();
    }else if(token() == 'D'){
      doloop();
    }else if(token() == 'R'){
      read();
    }else if(token() == 'O'){
      output();
    } else {
      assnmt();
    }
}
```

I don't see any good reason for these abbrevations either in this day and age, and language.

To answer your question about the `if` statement:

```
private void ifstatement() {
    match('I');
    comprsn();
    match('@');
    statement();
    if (token() == '%') {
        statement();
    }
    if (token() != '&') {
        syntax_error("'&' expected");
    }
}
```

To answer the second extension about `{` statement ... `}`, this is represented in the grammar by

```
statement ::= '{' statement ... '}'
```

and this is implemented in `statement()` thus:

```
private void statement(){
    if (token == '{') {
        do {
            statement();
        } while (token() != '}');
    } else if(token() == 'I'){
      ifstmt();
    }else if(token() == 'D'){
      doloop();
    }else if(token() == 'R'){
      read();
    }else if(token() == 'O'){
      output();
    } else {
      assnmt();
    }
}
```

Note that I'm completely ignoring the issue of when tokens get consumed, as you haven't told us how your `token()` and `match()` methods work.

Comment: Thanks, so this'll work fine? Just wanted to know if I had the right idea, with the abbreviations are you talking about "statemt"? It was given so I just followed it, wasn't my idea.

Also what would you use to code the optional case [ A | B ] ?

Comment: "opratr", "oprnd", "statemt", "assnmt", etc. Takes me back 30 years. Frighful. I don't know what you mean by `[A | B]`. It doesn't appear in the grammar.

Comment: Haha. It's all my professor's work there. Specifically this: "ifstmt  ::= I comprsn @ {statemt} [% {statemt}] &" 

There's the [% {statement}] in there that i'm not sure how to code. I know it's optional to go to "%" or the loop but I'm not sure if I'm thinking about the coding correctly.

Comment: Well, if the input token is '%', call statement(). Either way the next token should be '&'.

Comment: As far as coding that, since the it's optional to not go through either the % and {statement} how would I do that? Do I do something like if(token() == '%') then match the '%' and go through a while loop with the {statemt}? That's the only way I could think of and I'm pretty sure it's correct, just double checking. I think that works if both the % and {statemt} needs printing but what if I want to skip that and just grab the '%' token withou the statemt.

Comment: I added it to the OP so it's easier to read, I would think that's incorrect

Comment: The part starting '%' is optional. If the '%' isn't there, the next token should be '&'. If it is there, parse a statement and *then* the next token should be '&'. Your last sentence doesn't make sense. There's no point in processing the '%' without the following statement. You don't need a while loop either. You already have `statement():` use it! See edit.

Comment: Oh! I understand now, I thought when it's inside the optional square brackets it could go to either '%' or the statement but both of them are optional and if it goes inside it will go through both. Thanks for clearing that up. However I would still need a while loop since the statemt is surrounded by {} meaning it can have more than 1.

Comment: @user2318083 **NO!** It is the responsibility of `statement()` to handle `{` and `}` and multiple statements, because that can occur anywhere a single statement can occur. It is only the responsibility of `ifstatement()` to call `statement()`. This is the essence of recursive descent parsing. It's easy. Don't write things twice. If you're doing that, you're doing it wrong. Essentially your grammar is missing a production for `stmt ::= '{' stmnt ... '}'`, and this production is implemented inside `statement().` See 2nd edit.

Comment: '{' isn't part of the token listed though so I don't think I could use that. That's essentially using the or('|') as a token. I added the match and token methods, still trying to grasp the statement recursive part, recursions always confuses things for me.

Comment: Well whatever the correct syntax is for statement lists is, you have to implement it as shown with the appropriate adjustments. But given that there wasn't a statement-list production in your original grammar it is questionable whether you have to implement it at all. If you do, this is how to do it. Not by littering `while` loops in all the wrong places. You need to get your head around recurstion: it's what this is all about, and it is what is being taught here.

Comment: Ok I will look into that. I just thought wherever there are loops in the syntax diagrams means there is going to be a while statement.

Comment: There is a loop in the code, but in the right place, and the correct place is in `statement`. The syntax of `if` doesn't have anything about statement-lists in it, and neither should the code.